# align items in enumeration

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align multiple items in enumeration with `&` but its not working.

```
\begin{enumerate} 

\item[(1)] $ f: &x \longmapsto 0\ $(const 0) 
\item[(2)] $ f_{\mbox{const 1}}:  &x \tab  \longmapsto 1  $(const 1) 

\end{enumerate}
```

What should I use instead?

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site :) This is a little off-topic, but manually numbering your list considerably defeats the point of the `enumerate` environment in the first place, part of which is to do the numbering for you, so that you can move things around, renumber things with incredible ease, etc. etc. If you want to change the style of the label there is an old-fashioned way, by muddling around with internals, or you can simply use the [`enumerate`](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/enumerate.pdf) package

Comment: It can't compile: `&` is to be used in a `tabular/array` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than giving code fragments it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile the following example twice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,eqparbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
  \item $\eqmakebox[mm][r]{$f$} \colon x \longmapsto 0$ (const~0)
  \item $\eqmakebox[mm][r]{$f_{\text{const~1}}$} \colon x \longmapsto 1$ (const~1)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The package [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) provides `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<pos>]{<stuff>}` which sets `<stuff>` in a box that is wide enough to fit all boxes with the same `<tag>`. You can change the `<pos>`ition of the alignment as needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `\colon` than `:`?

Comment: @Bernard: Sure!